# #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tb_X'

Tags: mysql

I got a problem when I was trying to join 3 tables.

Below are the mysql syntax i was using :

```
SELECT
FROM carecell
LEFT JOIN staff ON cc.id_pks = staff.id_emp
LEFT JOIN staff ON cc.id_wpks = staff.id_emp
INNER JOIN member ON member.id_member = staff.id_member
```

Please Help me.. What should I do in order to fix the syntax?

Answer (score 3):

The SQL engine cannot distinguish between the two `staff` tables in the `from` clause.  You need to give them different names.  Something like this:

```
FROM carecell cc LEFT JOIN
     staff s1
     ON cc.id_pks = s1.id_emp LEFT JOIN
     staff s2
     ON cc.id_wpks = s2 .id_emp INNER JOIN
     member m
     ON m.id_member = s2.id_member
```

Answer (score 1):

If you join the same table multiple times you need to give that table each time a different alias name so the DB engine can differ between them

```
SELECT *
FROM carecell as cc
LEFT JOIN staff as s1 ON cc.id_pks = s1.id_emp
LEFT JOIN staff as s2 ON cc.id_wpks = s2.id_emp
INNER JOIN member as m ON m.id_member = s1.id_member
```

You already used aliases since you gave `carecell` the alias `cc`. In the last line of your query I joined `s1` but you have to decide which one to take - `s1` or `s2`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM carecell
LEFT JOIN staff t1 ON cc.id_pks = t1.id_emp
LEFT JOIN staff t2 ON cc.id_wpks = t2.id_emp
INNER JOIN member ON member.id_member = t1.id_member
```